# retrieve list of filtered users from list

Tags: powershell, csv, filter, import

I am having the hardest time figuring this out. I am trying to import a list of office numbers from a csv that corresponds to the office numbers in specific users profiles for that office. For example, i am trying to find all the contractors and customer service employees only for all offices listed. so in column A it should be listing the offices and column B should list the users for that office in a single row joined by a ; but some reason i get no output no errors. What am i doing wrong?

```
import-csv "C:\scripts\offices.csv" | 
    foreach {get-aduser -properties * -filter {office -eq "$($_.office)" -and title -eq "Independent contractor" -or office -eq "$($_.office)" -and title -eq "Sr customer service Rep"} | 
        select @{n='Name';e={$_.Name -join '; '}}} | 
            export-csv "c:\temp\users in each office.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but I think you need to wrap the conditions with () to group them appropriately.  Something like this:

```
-filter {(office -eq "$($_.office)" -and title -eq "Independent contractor") -or (office -eq "$($_.office)" -and title -eq "Sr customer service Rep")}
```

Or you could change it to this as well:

```
-filter {office -eq "$($.office)" -and (title -eq "Independent contractor" -or title -eq "Sr customer service Rep")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test, but an obvious error is the missing underscore in your filter:

-filter {office -eq "$($.office)"

should be:

```
-filter {office -eq "$($_.office)"
```

Comment: I did not catch that, for some reason it did not copy over from the ps1 properly. The underscore is in the script, weird.

Comment: update the question, and I'll delete this answer, then.

Comment: Then I'll leave it for now.

Comment: i had alot of help and this one gets me alot closer; $users=import-csv 'C:\Scripts\offices.csv' | 
     Foreach-Object{
          $office=$_.office
          Get-AdUser -Properties office -filter {office -eq $office -and (title -eq 'independent contractor' 

-or title -eq 'sr Customer Service rep')}
    } 

$users | Select $($office).Office | group office but heres the output i get                                                        Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    8 450                       {CN=user1,OU=CSR,OU=Users,OU

Comment: You should add that comment to your question, or update the question with that information.

Comment: Just saw your last comment here user2402045, so my answer is unneeded.